# What does the "thaumaturgy hazard trefoil" look like?

Tags: laundry-files

In the real world we have a nuclear hazard trefoil and a biohazard trefoil.
Apparently in Charles Stross' Laundry Files universe there is a thaumaturgy hazard trefoil.

Quoting from *The Concrete Jungle*:

> I reach in and carefully pick up a silver locket on a chain; there’s a yellow-and-black thaumaturgy hazard trefoil on a label dangling from it, and NO PULL ribbons attached to the clasp

Are there any images depicting it about?
From the book cover, or maybe from a tie-in game,
or even some fan art that the author has said "looks about right."

Comment: A thing I've wondered about myself when reading the LF. It sounds very similar to the nuclear one

Comment: @DannyMcG - It's much more like the biohazard symbol

Comment: Does The Concrete Jungle have another title? I can't find it in the list.

Comment: It is a novella that is sold as part of the The Atrocity Archives (which is two books: The Atrocity Archive, and the Concrete Jungle), but at various points it has been made available as a stand-alone novella.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This image is from Charles Stross' [official Merchandise site](https://www.zazzle.com/laundry_hse_compliant_black_t_shirt-235302389096356162)

[image]

Comment: But...  Copying the shape of the biohazard symbol completely defeats the whole process that was taken to produce a _unique_ and _distinct_ symbol.  :-P  Not that you're at all wrong (have an upvote) but I object to the failure of imagination.

Comment: @DavidW - Except that it's all eldritch and wibbly-wobbly

Comment: But from a distance, or through smoke or with your glasses out, it's not distinct enough.  I know Stross specified "trefoil" in the text (even though a five-sided figure would have been a better choice), but it should at least have been a completely different shape.  Pointy, possibly, *definitely* without the inner circle.  Maybe pairs of tentacles grasping an eye...  Just radically different in overall shape.

Comment: @DavidW that might be the goal -- if civilians spot it from afar and stay away thinking its a biohazard, that's still mission accomplished with minimal information leakage

Comment: Disappointing design

Comment: I concur with the expressions of disappointment. If it's wibbly-wobbly without the timey-wimey, why bother? And no, putting apertures at the convergence of the arcs doesn't pass the sniff test for uniqueness.

Comment: I was struck by @DavidW's suggestion of a pentagonal warning shape. Just taking the classic biohazard symbol and making it pentagonal looks something like this: [Pentagonal biohazard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPzU7.png)

Comment: @NickMatteo: The danger is that certain rather sensitive people may decide that that image is an allusion to satanism. If you turn it around so that the point is at the top, then it looks more Wiccan, but some people will (incorrectly) conflate the two.

Comment: @Kevin: I don't see the problem. Making people think it's bad/dangerous is the point.

Comment: @NickMatteo: That's fine for in-universe purposes, but you just *know* that somebody will try to get your book banned if you actually publish something like that.